# What is the main purpose and practical use of the absolute element of the position property in css? How is it used in modern websites?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, position, absolute

I understand how the absolute element works in a document, but I don't understand how what it can do can be applicable or used in modern website. Could anyone give me some examples of what it can be used for in a modern website or examples of it being used? Thanks

Comment: what do you mean modern website? Can you give some examples of how do they look? Absolute element positioning is a way of structuring elements on the page and you can use it in a very different way, more often without alternative.

Comment: When I say a modern website, I think of a website or webpage that any professional or amateur could create today. The more that I think about it, the more I think that I may just need to gain more experience in web development as I am very very new and that in doing so I might be able to find examples and places to use 'Absolute' on a webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The absolute element positioning can be handy in many ways. One pratical case to use it, which I mostly do is to position the eye in a password input.
That is to toggle between showing the password or not